# python passing function to class

Tags: python

Im writing simple telnetlib based lib, to use by other python scripts. Im also using logging class, and therefore I got one question: Is it possible, and is it good python practice to do things like that:

```
def printd(args):
    """ debug on stdout """
    sys.stdout.write(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S ") + args.rstrip() + '\n')

def printe(args):
    """ error on stderr """
    sys.stderr.write(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S ") + args.rstrip() + '\n')


class Connections:
    """ Telnet lib connection wrapper """

    def __init__(self, host, port, timeout, logger):
        """ if external logger is passed -  all msgs will be passed to it,
        otherwise will use printd and printe functions """

        self.timeout = timeout
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.connections = {}

        try:
            res = isinstance(logger, logging.Logger)
        except TypeError:
            res = False
        except:
            res = False

        if res == True:
            self.log = logger
            self.log_debug = self.log.debug
            self.log_info = self.log.info
            self.log_error = self.log.error
        else:
            self.log_debug = printd
            self.log_error = printe

    def connect2(self, helloMsg):
        try:
            self.c = telnetlib.Telnet(self.host, self.port)
        except socekt.error:
            self.c = None
            self.log_error("Could not connect to %s:%d" % (self.host, self.port))
        except IOError:
            self.log_error("Could not connect to %s:%d" % (self.host, self.port))
            self.c = None
```

In constructor Im passing logger, and if it exist, I want to use its log methods to print messages, if not, I want to use `printd` and `printe` functions.

Comment: Don't catch exceptions that you don't know what they are or what caused them. If you don't know what they are, you can't handle them correctly and you make your code harder to debug.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is perfectly fine in principle, except that `isinstance(logger, logging.Logger)` will never raise a `TypeError`. It will just return a boolean. It's easier and more pythonic to write

```
def __init__(self, host, port, timeout, logger=None):
    if logger is None:
        self.log_debug = printd
        self.log_error = printe
    else:
        # use the logger's methods
```

Then you can pass `None` to get the built-in logging.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance If classinfo is not a class, type, or tuple of classes, types, and such tuples, a TypeError exception is raised.

Comment: @JosiP: but `logging.Logger` is a type, so the exception is not raised. It's only raised for incorrect use of `isinstance`.

Comment: why not default to `None` on init ? `__init__(self, host, port, timeout, logger=None)`

Answer (score 0):

This seems fine to me. The main problem is that you leave `self.log_info` undefined in case you don't receive a logger.

An alternative would be to create a "synthetic" logger object as your default `self.log`.